# Export settings manually in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I just reinstalled Ubuntu after backing up my old home folder. Now I have my home folder back but found that I would have had to do `File | Export settings` beforehand in order to do `File | Import settings` now.

I still have my old `PyCharmCE2019.1` folder, though, it's just not in the format that is importable by Pycharm.

Is there a way I can manually bring this folder into the right format (I'm thinking probably by zipping some sub-folder or something)? Or do I just have to apply all the settings by hand again?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a full answer but I made the following experiment, I exported my settings via the `File` menu and checked what was inside the exported zip file.

Here's the list of folders and files that are all located in the `config` folder:

- `codestyles/` with inside `Default`, xml file
- `colors/` with inside an .icls file named with the theme you had I
  think (mine is named `Monokai2`)
- `inspection/` with inside `Default`, xml file
- `keymaps/` with inside `Default copy`, xml file
- `options/` with many xml files (26 files over the 38 original files
  from this folder)
- A file named `IntelliJ IDEA Global Settings`

This is from PyCharm 2019.1, pro edition.

Replacing one of the `default.xml` files by hand, would be a first step to see if you can at least re-import some of these settings manually.